# Display label with both direction symbols

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling

I have a line layer describing a road network, with traffic attribute values for both driving directions.
I would like to display label for both traffic values with direction symbols (above label is traffic in digit direction) :

```
   1500 >
----------->
   < 2200
```

Direction symbols option works perfectly but displays only one direction symbols :

```
   1500
----------->
   2200 >
```

I managed do display two direction symbols using an expression :

```
'<' || "dir_1" || '\n' || "dir_2" || '>'
```

but it's correct or not depending on the line orientation :

```
             1500 >                 1500 >
correct : <-----------   wrong : ----------->
             < 2200                 < 2200
```

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your all lines have the good orientation...

Then, I found the same problem but I think I found an alternative solution...
It seems that the return direction doesn't work.

If you make two labeling rules for the both directions :

- 1 left testing if left label column is not null
- 1 right testing if right label column is not null

For the right direction (return) you can checking the box "invert direction" i think it works... 
I do not know if there is a better solution...

Comment: my left and right label columns are usually not null...